# Gmail + own domain

Tags: g-suite, google

I want to ask, if it is possible to have normal Google account and have own domain (@example.com). I saw this [documentation](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251241?hl=en), and it should be possible, but when I wanted to create domain via Google, it said that I need Google Suite Basic. And I am worried about that, because Google Suite Basic has problem with some other services (Google Assistant, Google Home).

So anybody knows, if it is possible to have own domain + standart Google account?

This is screen from payment of domain:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For enabling Gmail service for a custom domain you have just 2 choiche:

1. [Subscribe a GSuite Edition](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6043385)
2. [Use the workaround that you had already suggested](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251241?hl=en):

   1. Register your custom Domain
   2. Access to your Domain mail settings and forward all incoming email to your private@gmail.com
   3. Access to your Gmail settings and enable Gmail to send messages as your custom Domain email address.